# PHPUnit, Selenium and Magento development environment

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, magento-1.6, browserstack

I have a Magento-based application and I'm trying to use PHPUnit with Selenium to test clicking on the links, but I keeps getting an error. I am also using the [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/), which could be causing the issue. Also, if anyone knows how to print out all the html in the terminal that would be great too.

```
//Use composer to insall phpunit-selenium

require '/home/mark/PhpstormProjects/Project/vendor/autoload.php';
define('BROWSERSTACK_USER', 'USERNAME');
define('BROWSERSTACK_KEY', 'TOKEN');

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{

    public static $browsers = [
        /* array(
             'browserName' => 'Safari',
             'host' => 'hub.browserstack.com',
             'port' => 80,
             'desiredCapabilities' => array(
                 'version' => '6.1',
                 'browserstack.user' => BROWSERSTACK_USER,
                 'browserstack.key' => BROWSERSTACK_KEY,
                 'os' => 'OS X',
                 'os_version' => 'Mountain Lion'
             )
         ),*/
        [
            'browserName'         => 'chrome',
            'host'                => 'hub.browserstack.com',
            'port'                => 80,
            'desiredCapabilities' => [
                'version'           => '30',
                'browserstack.user' => BROWSERSTACK_USER,
                'browserstack.key'  => BROWSERSTACK_KEY,
                'os'                => 'Windows',
                'os_version'        => '8.1'
            ]
        ]
        /* array(
             'browserName' => 'IE',
             'host' => 'hub.browserstack.com',
             'port' => 80,
             'desiredCapabilities' => array(
                 'version' => '11.0',
                 'browserstack.user' => BROWSERSTACK_USER,
                 'browserstack.key' => BROWSERSTACK_KEY,
                 'os' => 'Windows',
                 'os_version' => '7'
             )
         )*/
    ];

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://www.example.com/');
        $this->assertEquals('Example Domain', $this->title());
    }

    public function testGoogle()
    {
        echo $this->getBrowser();

        $this->url('http://www.google.com/');
        $element = $this->byName('q');
        $element->click();
        $this->keys('Browserstack');
        $button = $this->byName('btnG');
        $button->click();
        $this->assertEquals('Browserstack - Google Search', $this->title());
    }

    public function testCheckout()
    {
        echo $this->getBrowser();

        $this->url('http://sitename/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3Rlc3QuamV3ZWxzdHJlZXQuY29tL2VhcnJpbmdz/product/1308/');

        $this->url('http://test.sitename.com/checkout/cart/');

        $this->assertEquals('Shopping Cart | sitename.com', $this->title());
        $element = $this->byXPath('/html/body/div[3]/section/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/button[2]');

        //ive also tried 
        $element = $this->byId('mfi5');
        //this id is generated by the version of magento we are using
        $this->click($element);

        $this->assertEquals('Checkout | sitename.com', $this->title());
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
WebTest::testCheckout
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=30.0.1599.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232923,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 29 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: '5-255-93-8', ip: '5.255.93.8', os.name: 'windows', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Windows\proxy\scoped_dir3904_2113}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=30.0.1599.101, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: db0a84a0384ebea5dc167bde8cba098f
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

after much testing and going through things I have this: this is Not using browser stack,, how easy would it be to use with browser stack also how would i remove the annoying sleep(); lines to something more cleaner

```
 public function testAddProductToBag()
{

    $this->url('http://test.project.dev/item3');
    //Selects medium from the drop down list
    $ringSizeOption = $this->byCssSelector('#select_4267 > option:nth-child(3)');
    $ringSizeOption->click();

    $addtoBag = $this->byXPath("//*[@title='Add to bag >>']");
    $addtoBag->click();


    sleep(7);

    //$this->timeouts()->implicitWait(7000);
    //Selects the total amount from the div in the top left corner
    $amountDiv = $this->byCssSelector('a.blog:nth-child(2) > label:nth-child(1)');
    $this->assertEquals("£48.60 (1)", $amountDiv->text(), "Error: Nothing in cart");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing that locally, not via BrowserStack?

Comment: I've not done that yet but the reason I'm using it is for the cross browser compatibility. However I will try to just using normal selenium and report back on Monday

Answer (score 0):

Running safari with the $this->keys('random text') doesn't work and this was my issue.

The ability to input a string into an input after selecting the input field seems to cause safari to crash.

So removing the Safari browser and an update to some code solved the issue..

I will now need to look into how to get the $this->keys() working correctly in Safari but reading through several articles I can't imagine I'm going to have much luck.